# Looping through SqlDataReader and assigning them to controls of the page (.aspx)

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

Since I am creating a blog slider, I want it to be dynamic so the latest blogs are retrieved from the database and shown on page. My issue is that I am able to retrieve 3 rows into reader() but unable to assign each row and its values to separate elements like header 'h3',

```
while(dr.Read())
{
    string h1= (string)dr["Value1"]; 
    string p= (string)dr["Value2"]; 
}
```

but my main concern is that only one row will be run like this, after that how will I have the remaining rows assigned to controls such as 'h3' and 'p'. The first slider is getting the data from reader but what about the remaining two sliders and it's components such as 'h3' and 'p'

How do I assign the 2nd and 3rd rows to the other controls such as h3 and 'p' ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

create a bean class

```
public class headers
{
   public string head{get;set;}
   public string  p{get;set;}
}
```

//now change ur code

```
 var objList = new List<headers>();
   while (dr.Read())
            {
                objDetails = new headers();
                objDetails .head = (string)dr["value1"];
                objDetails .p= (string)dr["value2"];
                objList.Add(objDetails);
            }
```

now u can do

```
h1=objList[0].head;
h2=objList[1].head;
h3=objList[2].head;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Anirudh, will i be then able to pass any method further to the public string p in the first block code u mentioned ? like i want to again select only 200 letters from the string p by passing it into method like this 
        public static string TruncateAtWord(string value, int length)
        {
            if (value == null || value.Length < length || value.IndexOf(" ", length) == -1)
                return value;

            return value.Substring(0, value.IndexOf(" ", length));
        }

Comment: the moment i add this new code, all the protected methods in the assembly have become red and says should have struct or class expected